# How should I organize a multipurpose website?

Tags: website-design, design, portfolio

I would like an external advice about how to organize my website.
I'm looking to make a design that look almost like [this](http://nextop.beautheme.com/home-photographer-photography-wordpress-theme/) but the problem is that I'm not only photographer. I would like to make a single page website, but the thing is that I want to show my works (Web design, videos, 3d modeling) and I also want to show some of my best photos.

I don't really know how I can make one photography section and one basic portfolio section. Should I seperate them in two pages for better design?

I was thinking about these options :

1. Make a landing page where you choose to go see my Portfolio Profile or Photography Profile. A bit like in this [example](http://www.janueljohnson.com/).
2. Make this same choice section, but under "Portfolio" on the website. That will bring you to the page with all works or photos.
3. Just have two different setion on the single page website? Also, in term of UX, if I show 9 works or photos, is it better to add a "More" link that is a new page with everything or is it better to have like 3 new one loading (infinite scrolling)?

Also, you should know that for my photography part, I don't only want to show photos like that, but be sorted by theme (Documentary, Nature) or travel (Spain, Germany). - Which one could be better?

Also, should I have same design between photography and works? For example, I was thinking about Grid (3 collumns) for works and for photography between masonry (with a nice lightbox) or full page photos (when you scroll down you have another photo, etc.)

So much to think about... I made my wireframe like 10 times and looked like 100 websites for inspiration. Can't decide of what's the best for this kind of website where I want to show differents things. One part professional and one part more casual like a hobby (for the moment at least). Maybe I should just forget the photography part?

Thank you very much for your advice in UX design.

Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of the options you are choosing between are great options for different use cases. You'll see all sorts of different designs on websites, portfolios, and themes because people are trying to accomplish different things.

If you're looking to sell prints or book professional shoots a landing page can be great to inform quickly and call the user to action, sort of like guiding them where you want to go. The example link looks nice because it creates a hierarchy that organizes the information there, that way if I'm the user I can get to what I'm looking for faster.

In terms of showing a few pictures and a more button vs infinite scroll depends on where that information is. If it's a separate gallery page having infinite scroll can be more pleasant to interact with but on a single page site where you have more information underneath it that the user might want to read it can get drowned out if they can't scroll past it or don't care about the pictures and just want to find the About You section.

In regards to the design between photography and works, consistency is great to help users understand the navigation. If they've seen your photography and can navigate and go to your other works to find they're different it can be cognitively jarring.

I would say if you've made plenty of wireframes, start building and trust your instinct. Good luck with the site!